# Delphi: How to use ShowWindow properly on external application

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, delphi-xe2

> **See also:**
>   [How can I tell if another instance of my program is already running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459554/how-can-i-tell-if-another-instance-of-my-program-is-already-running)

i use the following code before starting my application, to check if another instance
of it is already started:

```
var _PreviousHandle : THandle;
begin
  _PreviousHandle := FindWindow('TfrmMainForm',nil);
  if _PreviousHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Application "" is already running!');
    SetForegroundWindow(_PreviousHandle);
    ShowWindow(_PreviousHandle, SW_SHOW);
    Application.Terminate;
    Exit;
  end;
...
```

However, if it has started, i need to show that application. The problem is after it is shown in this way the minimize button no longer works, and when i click the icon in the taskbar, it "unminimizes" and the animation that is shown is as if it was minimized. Am i missing something? is there a proper way to activate and show external application while it's minimized?

Comment: you should use `Mutex` to do this check and broadcast mesasge to notify existing instance

Comment: The problem is not how to tell if my program is running, but rather how to activate it properly from another instance of that program.

Comment: send broadcast message with known code (`RegisterWindowMessage`), then handle this message in program and let program to restore itself.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've seen the answer in the [`RestoreWindow`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/460480/960757) procedure there.

Comment: ertx, please check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12949757/800214

Comment: What would help here would be if you could produce a complete program that would allow us to reproduce what you report. Because a plain vanilla app doesn't behave the way you describe.

Comment: Right now i am trying to create a Mutex, if that doesn't work i will produce a demo program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a complete project, which keeps running only one instance of the application, and which should bring already running instance window to front.

You can download a [`testing project`](http://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/downloads/detail?name=14440717.zip) or try the code, which follows:

***Project1.dpr***

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Windows,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

var
  Mutex: THandle;
const
  AppID = '{0AEEDBAF-2643-4576-83B1-8C9422726E98}';
begin
  MessageID := RegisterWindowMessage(AppID);

  Mutex := CreateMutex(nil, False, AppID);
  if (Mutex <> 0) and (GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) then
  begin
    PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, MessageID, 0, 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

***Unit1.pas***

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StrUtils, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    function ForceForegroundWindow(WndHandle: HWND): Boolean;
    function ForceRestoreWindow(WndHandle: HWND; Immediate: Boolean): Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var AMessage: TMessage); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MessageID: UINT;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

function TForm1.ForceForegroundWindow(WndHandle: HWND): Boolean;
var
  CurrThreadID: DWORD;
  ForeThreadID: DWORD;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (GetForegroundWindow <> WndHandle) then
  begin
    CurrThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(WndHandle, nil);
    ForeThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow, nil);
    if (ForeThreadID <> CurrThreadID) then
    begin
      AttachThreadInput(ForeThreadID, CurrThreadID, True);
      Result := SetForegroundWindow(WndHandle);
      AttachThreadInput(ForeThreadID, CurrThreadID, False);
      if Result then
        Result := SetForegroundWindow(WndHandle);
    end
    else
      Result := SetForegroundWindow(WndHandle);
  end;
end;

function TForm1.ForceRestoreWindow(WndHandle: HWND;
  Immediate: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  WindowPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Immediate then
  begin
    WindowPlacement.length := SizeOf(WindowPlacement);
    if GetWindowPlacement(WndHandle, @WindowPlacement) then
    begin
      if (WindowPlacement.flags and WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED) <> 0 then
        WindowPlacement.showCmd := SW_MAXIMIZE
      else
        WindowPlacement.showCmd := SW_RESTORE;
      Result := SetWindowPlacement(WndHandle, @WindowPlacement);
    end;
  end
  else
    Result := SendMessage(WndHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0) = 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var AMessage: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if AMessage.Msg = MessageID then
  begin
    if IsIconic(Handle) then
      ForceRestoreWindow(Handle, True);
    ForceForegroundWindow(Application.Handle);
  end;
end;

end.
```

***Tested on OS versions:***

- Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Windows 7 SP1 64-bit Home Premium
- Windows XP SP 3 32-bit Professional

***Known issues and limitations:***

- The `MainFormOnTaskbar` is not taken into account at all; it must be set to True at this time

Comment: It does the same as my code. Seems that the problem is not with acquiring handle in a different way, but calling ShowWindow from a different application. (minimize button remains inactive)

Comment: What OS do you have ? I've tested this on Windows 7 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: This issue persists on Windows 7 Professional, not administrator user (that might have some affect)

Comment: Try the project from the update...

Comment: Thank you, i think my mutex didn't work because i didn't had 'MainFormOnTaskbar' set to true, well i thought i did, but that seems to have fixed everything for me. Also good point about using GUID for uniqueness.

Comment: @TLama - Most complete answer as usually!

Answer (score 4):

You're asking your Main form to show, but it may occur the application hidden window itself is minimized when you minimize the application to the task bar, in case of [`MainFormOnTaskBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormOnTaskBar) being false.

Don't call the ShowWindow method from the oustide. IMHO it's better if you pass a message to the application and respond from inside, calling the [`Application.Restore`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Restore)` method, which performs the proper ShowWindow calls among other things.

Comment: Sertac, TApplication.Restore takes into account MainFormOnTaskBar and ShowMainForm, so it's better to resort to it.

Comment: @Sertac, I added a clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem with VCL apps, and has been asked and answered many many times in the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero forums over the years.  Using `ShowWindow()` in this manner does not work for VCL windows very well because of the way the `MainForm` interacts with the `TApplication` object at runtime, especially in different versions of Delphi.  What you should do instead is have the second instance send a custom message to the first instance, and then let the first instance restore itself as needed when it receives the message, such as by setting its `MainForm.WindowState` property, or calling `Application.Restore()`, etc, and let the VCL work out the details for you, like @jachguate suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The following works well for me. I'm not 100% certain I have fully understood the question though, so do let me know if I've got it wrong.

```
var
  _PreviousHandle: HWND;
  WindowPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
....
WindowPlacement.length := SizeOf(WindowPlacement);
GetWindowPlacement(_PreviousHandle, WindowPlacement);
if WindowPlacement.flags and WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED<>0 then
  WindowPlacement.showCmd := SW_MAXIMIZE
else
  WindowPlacement.showCmd := SW_RESTORE;
SetWindowPlacement(_PreviousHandle, WindowPlacement);
SetForegroundWindow(_PreviousHandle);
```

Note that the correct type for `_PreviousHandle` is `HWND` and not `THandle`.

Comment: SW_RESTORE always "re-sized" version of the application's main window, It's not quite the expected behavior.

Comment: @ertx What is the expected behavior?

Comment: To see the other program the way as if it was activated from user. It doesn't matter which ShowWindow() command i use, the form is activated, but the windows thinks it's still minimized, so the minimize button does not work.

Comment: _PreviousHandle := FindWindow('TfrmMainForm',nil);
  if _PreviousHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Application "" is already running!');
    ShowWindow(_PreviousHandle, SW_RESTORE);
    SetForegroundWindow(_PreviousHandle);
  end
else
  begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMainForm, frmMainForm);
  Application.Run;
  end;

Comment: @bummi, i am sorry but your solution does not work either, minimize key still remains inactive

Comment: @ertx My updated answer addresses the point you made in your first comment.