# How can I make the second instance of my program pass control back to the first instance?

Tags: delphi

I have create an application with Delphi XE3.
My application have a trayicon (I use TCoolTrayIcon for this) so when the user minimize it there is not a icon on taskbar but only on trayicon.

To avoid more that one istance of my application I use this code:

```
procedure CreateMutexes(const MutexName: String);
const
  SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION = 1;
var
  SecurityDesc: TSecurityDescriptor;
  SecurityAttr: TSecurityAttributes;
  MutexHandle: THandle;
begin
  InitializeSecurityDescriptor(@SecurityDesc, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
  SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(@SecurityDesc, True, nil, False);
  SecurityAttr.nLength := SizeOf(SecurityAttr);
  SecurityAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor := @SecurityDesc;
  SecurityAttr.bInheritHandle := False;
  MutexHandle := CreateMutex(@SecurityAttr, False, PChar(MutexName));

  if MutexHandle <> 0 then
    begin
      if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then
        begin
          MessageBox(0, 'You cannot start more than one instance of ContLab.'
                      + #13#10 + 'Use the instance has already started.',
                       'ContLab', mb_IconHand);

          CloseHandle(MutexHandle);
          Halt;
        end
    end;

  CreateMutex(@SecurityAttr, False, PChar('Global\' + MutexName));
end;
```

In this way when the user start application 2 times he get an error message and the second instance is terminate.

Now I'd like not show the error message but open the main form of first instance of application and terminate the second instance.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. What's your real question?

Comment: Found a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/460480/1970843

Comment: @KenWhite, your comment is a dupe of GabrielF's comment :-) Anyway this question is about how to open the main form of first instance, while the linked question asks how to detect if another application is running.

Comment: I agree with @Lurd. Although the supposed duplicate includes an answer to this question, they are separate questions. The answer in the other question is a case of *scope creep*. It answers the logical next question (this one), but not particularly *well*. It's much better to keep the two tasks in separate questions. That's why I've voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to send a message to the other application to request that it shows itself.

First of all you need to find the other application's main window. There are many ways to do that. For instance you can use `FindWindow`. Or you can enumerate the top-level windows with `EnumWindows`. Typically you'd then check for matching window text and/or class name.

Once you've found the main window of the other instance, you need to give it the ability to set itself to be the foreground window. You need to call `AllowSetForegroundWindow`.

```
var
  pid: DWORD;
....
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndOtherInstance, pid);
AllowSetForegroundWindow(pid);
```

Then send the window a user-defined message. For instance:

```
const
  WM_RESTOREWINDOW = WM_APP;
....
SendMessage(hwndOtherInstance, WM_RESTOREWINDOW, 0, 0);
```

Finally, your other instance's main form needs to listen for this message.

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ....
  protected
    procedure WMRestoreWindow(var Message: TMessage); message WM_RESTOREWINDOW;
  ....
  end;
```

When it encounters the message it must do this:

```
procedure TMainForm.WMRestoreWindow(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Visible := True;
  Application.Restore;
  Application.BringToFront;
end;
```

---

I'm a little sceptical of your mutex handling code. I don't understand the need for security attributes since you are creating it in the local namespace. But then I see a second call to `CreateMutex` that ignores the return value, but creates an object in the global namespace.

Comment: You don't need the user-defined messages mechanism. You just need to call ShowWindow and SetForegroundWindow to the first instance's handle (I've linked a dupe with all the code). This solution is too complicated.

Comment: Deleted my answer, your way to send a message to the first app is the way to go. For more on the problems with my now-deleted answer, see @RemyLebeau answer [Delphi: How to use ShowWindow properly on external application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14446381/576719). Problem with `ShowWindow()` from external application.

Comment: @LU RD, even what Remy describes there I've tried when I was dealing with this problem. Even that was not enough... (but maybe it does in Delphi XE3)

Comment: @TLama, `TrayIcon` and oneinstance has always been trublesome.

Comment: I don't remember why I do it this way, but this is how my program has done it for years.

Comment: @LURD Yes it seems to, although it screws up my apps notification icon but I expect that is unrelated. But that's not extensively tested. Why do you think it would be a problem?

Comment: I don't remember the exact details, but there were problems to get correct behaviour minimizing/maximizing when an application was started with `MainFormOnTaskbar` false, in conjuction with one app instances. It could work in one Delphi version, but not in the next, etc.

Comment: @LURD I think modern Delphi's are better. And calling the code in my answer from the app itself I suspect is better than poking from the outside. But I don't know more details. I know that the code in my answer works fine in my setting.

Comment: It's obvious why handling restoration in the target application (f.i. on receiving a message) is better, see `Application.InternalRestore`. When you force it from the outside, you bypass all that unpleasant stuff that have to run that the TApplication framework imposes, when you don't have MainFormOnTaskbar f.i.

Comment: @Sertac Thanks. That was my instinctive thought, but I cannot formulate it very clearly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have create a very small application based on your answer: a black form without trayicon. However I cannot restore the form of first instance from minimize status. [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19900180/OneInstance.zip

Comment: @Martin, declare your method like this: `procedure WMRestoreWindow(var Message: TMessage);  message WM_RestoreWindow;`

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I missed that comment somehow. What LURD says is right. That's all you need to do.