# Force another application SendToBack

Tags: delphi

I need my form in front of an application. However, the common methods do not work.

**Methods already tried**

```
//method #1

PostMessage(HD, WM_USER, 0, 0);
SetWindowPos(HD, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);


//method #2
dwThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(HD, nil);
dwCurrentThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId;
AttachThreadInput(dwCurrentThreadID, dwThreadID, true);
BringWindowToTop(Aff.handle);
ShowWindow(Aff.handle, SW_SHOW);
```

**Application in question**
[image]

**Comments**

The application in question only works in full screen mode.

I do not want complete code, only a way forward.

Excuse me for my bad English and thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have FormStyle = fsStayOnTop?

Comment: Yes and don`t work just with this app

Comment: Do you get a good handle in HD??

Comment: Yes Work Fine with others apps all methods

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your form to the bottom. To make it topmost:

```
SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Another approach, if you really want to force external application to the background you need to get its handle. For example, if such application is named calc:

```
hCalc := FindWindow('calc', nil); 
SendMessage(hCalc , WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0); // you can also minimize the application
SetWindowPos(hCalc , HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0,  SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks for try help but does not work.
the application is in front of all up to open the task manager he can not stay in focus always is back.

Comment: So you have an application that stay on top even when Task Manager is moved to the same position?

Comment: Do you have your application in VMWare Player and expect it to be on top of some other application that is not in the same virtual environment? Maybe complete screenshot might explain the situation.

Comment: but the application was developed in order to not leave other applications in front of him. and the image is complete my application this back this full screen

Comment: This can be guaranteed on Windows XP but not on newer versions.

Comment: this running on Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function ForceForegroundWindow(AHandle: THandle): Boolean;
var
  Input: TInput;
begin
  Result := True;

  ZeroMemory(@Input, SizeOf(Input));
  SendInput(1, Input, SizeOf(Input));
  SetForegroundWindow(AHandle);
end;
```

Credits to Sertac Akyuz from ([How to bring my application to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946150/how-to-bring-my-application-to-the-front/12950454#12950454))

Comment: Thank you think it will help me a lot

Comment: This should not be an answer but a comment referring to Sertac's answer, so -1

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Sorry i didn't find the original thread. Credits added.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks. Anyway I doubt 3v3lyn has a user32 window at all, but perhaps a dx surface or such. Probably none of the recommendations on this page will help..